# Qt4 application crash, segmentaton fault when click connected button

Tags: c++, qt4

I've created a simple application with QGraphicsView and I have a problem with connected button.
There is a simple window with QGraphicsScene and one QPushButton and a function which should add a rectangle to my scene. Compilation is ok, it works and after I click this button application crash.

.h file:

```
class Canvas : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Canvas(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void addPoint();

private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QPushButton *btn;

};
```

.cpp file:

```
Canvas::Canvas(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    vbox->setSpacing(1);
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("test", this);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    view->setScene(scene);
    vbox->addWidget(view);
    vbox->addWidget(btn);
    setLayout(vbox);
    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addPoint()));
}

void Canvas::addPoint()
{
    scene->addRect(100,0,80,100);
}
```

Also debuger said:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

And points this line:

```
{ return addRect(QRectF(x, y, w, h), pen, brush); }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To helps with that we mcve, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement in your constructor is a local variable definition and initialization:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
```

The actual `scene` member variable is never initialized and anything that tries to use `this->scene` will crash the application.

As you want to initialize the existing `scene` variable, you should omit the type in front of the variable:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
```

Comment: Member btn is also shadowed by a local variable in the constructor; this will cause segfaults when trying to access it from other methods, too.
Hint: Try to avoid ambigous variable/method names. Member variables should be prefixed by _ or m_ or similar. Use -Wshadow (GCC option) to find potential clashes.